# How to declare and assign value to a variable before query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a complicated query that has to use a number called `SubUnitRate`. This variable comes from another table with special condition. in short we have:

```
DECLARE
SUBUNITRATE   NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT NVL (NULLIF (CU.SUBUNITRATE, 0), 1)
 INTO SUBUNITRATE
 FROM CURRENCYS CU
      JOIN ACCOUNTS ACC ON CU.ID = ACC.CURRENCY
WHERE ACC.ID = :ACCOUNTID;
END;
SELECT SUBUNITRATE * 100 FROM DUAL;
```

My goal is to acquire the result of(in simple case):

```
SELECT SUBUNITRATE * 100 FROM DUAL;
```

But how is that possible?

Comment: mayby you could create a stored fucntion submitRate(varchar2 accountID)

Comment: Or don't use PL/SQL at all and make this a subquery instead.

Comment: By "simplifying" your query you have made it hard for us to understand what you are trying to achieve and so harder for use to help you. Please provide an actual explanation of your actual needs.

Comment: make it a function and return subunitrate * 100; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the value of SUBUNITRATE multiple times in the same query you could use the WITH clause:

```
with cte as ( 
   select case 
            when CU.SUBUNITRATE = 0 then 1 
            else CU.SUBUNITRATE 
          end as SUBUNITRATE
   FROM CURRENCYS CU
   JOIN ACCOUNTS ACC ON CU.ID = ACC.CURRENCY
   WHERE ACC.ID = :ACCOUNTID
    )
select cte.SUBUNITRATE * 100
from cte;
```

Answer (score 2):

A PL/SQL block cannot return the results of a query as a query.  Instead, you can print the results out.

So, does this do what you want?

```
DECLARE
    SUBUNITRATE   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(NULLIF(CU.SUBUNITRATE, 0), 1)
    INTO SUBUNITRATE
    FROM CURRENCYS CU JOIN
         ACC
         ON CU.ID = ACC.CURRENCY
    WHERE ACC.ID = :ACCOUNTID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBUNITRATE * 100)
END;
```

Comment: As I said, the variable has to be used in more complicated query that simplified as 'SUBUNITRATE * 100'. so I need to use it multiple of times afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

No need for PL. APC' solution, simplified and in a form you can use directly in your query (wherever you would say ... = subunitrate, say ... = (select sur from cte) instead - including the parentheses):

```
with cte_prelim as (select subunitrate from ... etc.),
cte (sur) as select case when subunit rate is null or subunitrate = 0 then 100
                    else subunitrate * 100 end from cte_prelim)
select...  (your query where you need to use the value)
```